# SQL Server Maintenance Plan failing - Failed to acquire connection "Local server connection"

Tags: security, sql-server-2005, maintenance

I've got a recently installed sql 2005 database server (an upgrade from 2000 on the same machine), I'm trying to get maintenance plans set up to reindex etc but they are constantly failing. This is the message I get, I presume some permission for some user somewhere is wrong but not really sure where I should be looking.

> Executed as user: 194709-DB2\SYSTEM.
>   ... 9.00.4035.00 for 64-bit  Copyright
>   (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-2005. All
>   rights reserved.    Started:  12:45:34
>   Error: 2009-07-20 12:46:05.42
>   Code: 0xC00291EC     Source:
>   {BDA7B017-98D2-41A4-864E-49A5A9B39855}
>   Execute SQL Task     Description:
>   Failed to acquire connection "Local
>   server connection". Connection may not
>   be configured correctly or you may not
>   have the right permissions on this
>   connection.  End Error  Warning:
>   2009-07-20 12:46:05.42     Code:
>   0x80019002     Source: OnPreExecute
>   Description: SSIS Warning Code
>   DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The
>   Execution method succeeded, but the
>   number of errors raised (1) reached
>   the maximum allowed (1); resulting in
>   failure. This occurs when the number
>   of errors reaches the number specified
>   in MaximumErrorCount. Change the
>   MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors. 
>   End Warning  Error: 2009-07-20
>   12:46:05.44     Code: 0xC0024104
>   Source: Reorganize Index Task
>   De...  The package execution fa... 
>   The step failed.

Comment: When you installed sql 2005, did it create a new instance or did it use the same default instance name?

Comment: I didn't actually do the installation, but it's running under an instance name of MSSQL2005

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating the jobs through sa from my machine connecting to the remote SQL Server instance doesn't work.  However if I RDP onto the machine and use my Windows credentials to set up the jobs up it works.

I didn't try it, but connecting to the sql server instance through Management Studio, using windows credentials would probably have worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check the connection within the package to make sure it is connecting to the correct server.  I've had a different scenario (instance fail-over) produce the same error message - i.e. on the packages running on the secondary server were trying to run against the original server name.

Comment: This is our problem, but how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion, open up your maintenance plan and select the connection from "Manage Connections..." (on the toolbar) and make sure you have given the correct credentials.

Answer (score -1):

It will failed even you configured it properly through the agent account itself. Sometimes in production scenarios many other jobs are also running which acquire the same connection on the same server. Due to this both jobs collide and will fail sometimes...